# I'm trying to convert accelerometer readings into servo movements

Tags: c++, arduino, accelerometer, arduino-uno

I'm using a memsic2125 accelerometer with an Arduino Uno and trying to convert the accelerometer readings into servo movements. After some calibration, the correct angle measure is returned (on a -90 to 90 degree scale)and then converted to a 0 to 360 scale for a continuous servo but the servo will not move at all. I am  unable to provide a photo of the circuitry but I believe my wiring and components are correct. The program I have is based on the one found at: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Memsic2125 . Sorry if the mistake is really obvious or blaring, I'm new to Arduino. Thank you.

```
//AccelerometerServoControlDelta
//Uma
//Based on source code from: 
//http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Memsic2125
//Using a Memsic2125 accelerometer

#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;

const xPin = 2;                                               //X-axis output
const yPin = 3;                                               //Y-axis output

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);                                          //Servo is connected to I/O pin 9

  Serial.begin(9600);                                         //Initaialize serial monitor communications

  pinMode(xPin, INPUT);                                       //Initialize accelerometer pins
  pinMode(yPin, INPUT); 
}

void loop() {
  int pulseX, pulse Y;                                        //Reads pulse       width for x-axis and y-axis
  int accelerationX, accelrationY;                            //Variables which will contain the acceleration
  int servoX;
  int servoY;

  pulseX = pulseIn(xPin, HIGH);                               //Read and assign the x and y pulses from the accelerometer
  pulseY - pulseIn(yPin, HIGH);           

  accelerationX = (((pulseX / 9.81) - 500) * 8) / 11) - 2;    //Division by the earth's acceleration
  accelerationY = (((pulseY / 9.81) - 500) * 8) / 11) - 7;    //Calculations after * 8 are for calibration purposes

  Serial.print(accelerationX);                                //Printing x and y axis degrees of rotaion to serial monitor
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(accelerationY);
  Serial.println();

  delay(100);

  servoX = map(accelerationX, -90, 90, 0, 360);               //Converting the degree measurement of the axis from -90 - +90 to 0 - +360
  myservo.write(servoX);                                      //Using the converted value and sending it to the servo as a degree of rotation

  delay(15);

}
```

Comment: We need the circuit schematic **and** the model/version of your servo.